# The right SQL or ActiveRecord formulation for complex query in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord model SentimentRecords with table sentiment_records where each record has attributes: user_id, sentiment_id,lecture_id, and timestamp.
My Query: Given a LECTURE_ID, and a DATETIME, for each sentiment_id, I want a count of how many user_id's (users) recorded each sentiment_id; for each user_id only counting the latest timestamp <= the given datetime.

Here is a formulation that isn't working:

```
SentimentRecords.find_by_sql
("SELECT sentiment_id,count(*) 
FROM sentiment_records WHERE id          
IN (SELECT max(id) FROM sentiment_records 
WHERE lecture_id=LECTURE_ID GROUP BY user_id 
WHERE timestamp <= DATETIME) GROUP BY sentiment_id")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct query, thanks to Nick Marden:

```
SentimentRecords.connection.select_all("SELECT sentiment_id, COUNT(*) FROM sentiment_records WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM sentiment_records WHERE lecture_id = LECTURE_ID AND timestamp < DATETIME GROUP BY user_id) GROUP BY sentiment_id")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the requirements, but I think you need SQL that's something like this.

```
select s1.sentiment_id, count(s1.user_id)
from sentiment_records s1
inner join (
    select user_id, max(timestamp) as timestamp
    from sentiment_records
    where timestamp <= ?
      and lecture_id = ?
    group by user_id
    ) s2 on s1.user_id = s2.user_id and s1.timestamp = s2.timestamp
where lecture_id = ?
group by s1.sentiment_id;
```